# How do you create links with a NULL or # in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Trying to create folders for links where the parent has no content, it's just a folder. Need to be able to insert #, but Drupal is saying it's not a link. Just want the user to click it and nothing happen, the child of that menu item will already be being displayed without a click.

**Version:** Drupal 6 (appears  worked in D5)

**I've attempted the following:** `'', #, <#>, empty, <empty>, null, <null>, blank, <blank>, <none>, none, <answer>` **...just kidding.**

**ERROR:** The path '`<insert_non-url>`' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.

Question, just ask -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the [Special Menu Items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module, which allows you to enter "nolink" as path. A 'nolink' menu item will render as a normal menu item without `<a>` tag, but you can style it differently if needed.

Comment: +1 I've seen that mod, but super hard to tell if it'll work with the system I have in place, or even worse create a conflict... guess I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, got some crazy error message "user warning: Duplicate entry"... :-) ...lucky it went away after I delete the mod.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes me wonder which modules you have enabled. I never had incompatibility problems with special menu items.

Comment: Re-problems with Special Menu Items, lots of people are having issues simply because you need to clear all caches after installing it for it to work!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#block-menu_block-1 li.expanded > a").removeAttr("href");
```

I use this to get rid of href of the first level of li a.
This makes it possible to use the first a links in a menu as non click able categories. 
This is a bit ugly but it works for smaller things :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a bogus link to anything, perhaps the homepage and then use jQuery to turn off the click by adding something like this:

`$('.menu-item-classorID').click(function(){ return false; });`

Quick and dirty method but does the trick in a pinch. Use menu attributes module to add class or ID to a menu item.

Comment: One common was is to link like this: href="#". That does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Http://#
```

Drupal takes it as input, but it returns an error in the navigation, but at least I've got a menu item. Posting this for now until someone post an answer that Drupal 6 takes as input, and does not produce an error.

Comment: This would be better as an edit to your question or a comment since it's not actually an answer.

Comment: @John Conde: I'm using it as an answer for now, meaning at the very least I'm able to create place holders, and move forward until I find a better answer.